# why tuple in list can strip brackets, example: [a: 1]

Tags: elixir

First, let's see normal list: `iex> z = [:a, 1]`.
And then first item of z, `List.first(z)`, is `:atom`, which value is `:a`.

Then, we create list like: `iex> z = [a: 1]`. Now, the first item of z, `List.first(z)`, is `Tuple`, which value is `{:a, 1}`.

Why? And is there's some related doc about this? Thx :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[a: 1, b: 2]` is a shortcut for a keyword list which is a list of tuples, where the first elem is an atom and the second element any term. So its equal to `[{:a, 1}, {:b, 2}]`. You can read about it here https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/keywords-and-maps.html